# jQuery flicker when using animate-scrollTo

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser

I have a problem with the `scrollTo` function when it is called by a jQuery `animate` function.

Here my code:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("body").animate({scrollTop: 1400},"slow");
});
```

When I click the button, the flicker appears before the body scrolling. For example, I'm on (scroll position) 1000, and when I clicked the button the following happened:

1. page/image on (scroll position) 1400 appears, it looks like I have already gone 
   to (position) 1400
2. then it moves again to (position) 1000, this happens so fast
   and looks like a flicker
3. finally it scrolls to 1400 like a normal scroll..

On firefox it always appears, and sometimes on chrome also.

Comment: Please provide a link to the scrollTo plugin for those needing it.

Comment: this is the sample.
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

and this is where i got the plugin.
http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Comment: solved (probably). I use scrollTo plugin for detect hash tag, and when the button was clicked, i set it return true so the hash appear on the link and make the browser move to the selected id first before animated. i set it as false again and now it animate normaly.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I had the same flickering problem. It was caused by the hash anchor in the link that triggers the function. Fixed it with preventDefault():

```
$("#button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").animate({scrollTop: 1400},"slow");
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify: The problem is caused, because (1) the browser executes the jump to the anchor (2) then jQuery jumps back and scrolls slow to the anchor.

Comment: Thx, this solves my problem too. But what if i use this in multiple dropdown menus, to scroll to the next one and the last one has an active anchor. This will stop from redirecting to href.

Answer (score 7):

```
<a href="#" onclick="return scrollFromTop(1400, 2000);">scroll</a>

function scrollFromTop(offset, duration) {
    $('body').stop(true).animate({scrollTop: offset}, duration);
    return false;
});
```

had the same problem... fixed it by returning false on the click handler

Comment: My problem got fixed after using .stop(true).

Answer (score 1):

solved this problem by stopping the animation like this:

```js
$('body,html').bind('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove', function(e){
            if ( e.which > 0 || e.type == "mousedown" || e.type == "mousewheel" || e.type == "touchmove"){
                $("html,body").stop();
            }
        })
```

found there: [Jquery .animate() stop scrolling when user scrolls manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445590/jquery-animate-stop-scrolling-when-user-scrolls-manually)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem while using "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar" package in laravel project. If that's your case, disable it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).