# Jquery .animate() stop scrolling when user scrolls manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have set up a snippet that scrolls a page section into view when it's clicked, the problem is that if the user wants to scroll in the middle of the animation the scroll kinda stutters.

```
    $( "section" ).click(function(e) {
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).position().top }, 'slow');
        return false; 
    });
```

How can I stop the jquery animation if the user scrolls manually?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Change your function to this:

```
var page = $("html, body");

$( "section" ).click(function(e) {

   page.on("scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove", function(){
       page.stop();
   });

   page.animate({ scrollTop: $(this).position().top }, 'slow', function(){
       page.off("scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove");
   });

   return false; 
});
```

This will:

- Stop the animation if the user scrolls manually (only during the animation)
- Does not obstruct your normal jQuery animation, such some of the other answers would

---

Some extra information:

> Why are you binding to all of those events? "scroll mousewheel etc..."

There are many different types of scroll events. You can scroll down using your mouse, keyboard, touchscreen, etc. With this we make sure to catch *all* of them.

> What is the use of `var page = $("html, body");`? Can't I just use `$("html, body")` everywhere?

If you use the same selector more than once, it's good practice to cache them in a [variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables). It will be easier to write/use, and has better performance than having the program re-calculate the selector every time.

> Where can I find more info on `.animate()` and `.stop()`?

You can read the jQuery documentation for [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/). I also recommend reading about [animation queue's](https://learn.jquery.com/effects/queue-and-dequeue-explained/) since `.stop()` works on this principle.

Comment: thanks,  it works perfectly. Just a question, I want to ignore clicks on <a> elements so it doesn't affect hyperlinks, I tried "section:not(a)" in the selector but it doesn't work. Could you edit the selector so it ignores links?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457246/jquery-click-function-exclude-children

Comment: I found that I had to remove the 'scroll' and 'keyup' from what was being bound, because the `.stop()` was triggering when initially clicking on `$('section')` (using this example)

Comment: You could also swap `on` for `one` and use a named function in `on/one` and `off` to make sure to only remove that particular handler.

Comment: +1 Thanks, @DarkAshelin. After searching a whole afternoon, this was the code that prevented the flickering of animation if the user scrolls.

Comment: the page.stop() is working for desktop but when opening the page on a smartphone the animation keeps the page stuck at it's place

Comment: This does not seem to work for me.  On an android phone, animation no longer works at all upon tapping a button.  Any solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I would do it by detecting user events

```
$('body,html').bind('scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove', function (e) {
  if (e.which > 0 || e.type == "mousedown" || e.type == "mousewheel" || e.type == "touchmove") {
    $("html,body").stop();
  }
});
```

Here is [a good tutorial](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/09/animated-scrolling-with-jquery-12).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("your selector").scroll(function(){
 $('html,body').stop();
});
```

reference **[stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('html,body').scroll(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, false);
});
```

It will also remove all other animations from the element's queue, but it won't "jump" to the end of the current scroll animation.

Comment: I believe this will obstruct his original scroll animation.