# Stop jquery scroll animation

Tags: jquery

Using the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

How can I let the user stop the animation once it's begun by clicking or moving the mouse wheel ?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Similar Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445590/jquery-animate-stop-scrolling-when-user-scrolls-manually