# Linear easing slows down

Tags: jquery, easing

1st question:
Can't figure out why .animate linear slows down when it comes to its destination point.
What am I missing ?

Weird thing is that going from middle pic upward it always works perfectly (only in that one case).

2nd question:
Is there a way to disable user from scrolling while animation is on-going ?

[edit]
I have cut out pictures so it is easier to debug
[/edit]

```js
$(document).ready( function (){
 var scrollCheck = 0;
 var heightVal = window.innerHeight;
   
   
 $(window).resize(function(){
   window.scroll(0,0);
   heightVal = window.innerHeight;
   hControl1 = heightVal -1;
   scrollCheck = 0;
 });

 var isScrolling = false;
  
 window.addEventListener("scroll", throttleScroll, false);
     
 function throttleScroll(e) {
   if (isScrolling == false) {
     window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
       scrolling(e);
       isScrolling = false;
       //console.log("Scrolling");
     });
   }
 isScrolling = true;
 }
     
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", scrolling, false);
 
 function scrolling(e) {
 var yValue = $(window).scrollTop();
      
   //1st photo, scroll down
   if ( yValue > 0 && scrollCheck === 0 ){
       
     $('body').stop().animate({scrollTop:heightVal}, 700, 'linear');
     if ( window.pageYOffset === heightVal ){
       scrollCheck = 1;
       //console.log(window.pageYOffset);
     }
   }//2nd photo, scroll up
   else if( yValue < heightVal  && scrollCheck === 1  ){
       
     $('body').stop().animate({scrollTop:(-heightVal)}, 700, 'linear');
     if ( window.pageYOffset === 0 ){
       scrollCheck = 0;
     }
   }//2nd photo, scroll down
   else if( yValue > heightVal  && scrollCheck === 1 ){

     $('body').stop().animate({scrollTop:(heightVal*2)}, 700, 'linear');
            if ( window.pageYOffset === (heightVal*2) ){
       scrollCheck = 2;
     }
   }//3rd photo, scroll up
   else if( yValue < heightVal*2 && scrollCheck === 2){

            $('body').stop().animate({scrollTop:(heightVal)}, 700, 'linear');
  if ( window.pageYOffset === heightVal ){
    scrollCheck = 1;
  }
   }
    }//end of scrolling(e) funcion
}); //end of $(document).ready
```

```css
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#section1,#section2,#section3{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#section1{
  background-color: grey;
}
#section2{
  background-color: green;
}
#section3{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='section1'></div>

<div id='section2'></div>

<div id='section3'></div>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce issue at stacksnippets?

Comment: @guest271314 I`ll try to do so

Comment: @guest271314 
Hm I'm afraid I don't know what you are actually asking for, I have went to stacksnippet.com although I don't see any option there to add/edit anything

Comment: See https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks ! will do that as soon as I`ll some time !

Comment: @guest271314 well that is one useful feature, thanks for making me familiar with, and as you can see it is done

Comment: Not related, but is there a reason your indentation is taking so much space? Not that it's a bad thing (it may be from a legibility stand point but anyway), just for curiosity...

Comment: @TiagoMarinho I`m goin to fix that right away !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`animate()` won't run linearly because you're calling it every time the `scroll` event is triggered. This happens because when you do this:

```
$("body").stop().animate({scrollTop: 0}, 700);
isScrolling = false;
```

The computer doesn't wait for the animation to complete to continue the program flow; instead, it starts the animation and procceeds, assigning `false` to the `isScrolling` variable immediately. In addition, your usage of `requestAnimationFrame` wasn't necessary, and it led the `isScrolling = false` assignment to run after `isScrolling = true` with virtually no delay — due to the [asynchronous nature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626680/is-settimeout-a-good-solution-to-do-async-functions-with-javascript) of those functions.

This causes the `scroll` event listener to call the `animate()` function every time it's triggered, because `isScrolling` is never `true`.

The problem can be solved by waiting for the `animate()` callback to assign `false` to `isScrolling`, removing the `requestAnimationFrame` call and it's `isScrolling = false;` assignment.

---

One last thing...

> Weird thing is that going from middle pic upward it always works perfectly (only in that one case).

No, it doesn't, but it looks like so because you set it to `{scrollTop: -heightVal}`, while it should be `{scrollTop: 0}`.

Note that I highly, **HIGHLY** recommend an extensive refactoring of functions and variable names. No one other than you can understand your code in less than 30 minutes.

Here's the result of all the changes above mentioned, including better naming:

```js
$(document).ready( function (){
var currentSection = 0;
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;


$(window).resize(function(){
    window.scroll(0,0);
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    hControl1 = windowHeight -1;
    currentSection = 0;
});

var isScrolling = false;


window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollSnappingController, false);

function scrollSnappingController(e) {
    if (isScrolling === false) {
            snapScrollToNextSection(e);
            console.log("first")
        isScrolling = true;
        console.log("second")
    }
}
function scrollEnded () {
    isScrolling = false;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", snapScrollToNextSection, false);

var section1 = $("#section1");
var section2 = $("#section2");
var section3 = $("#section3");

function snapScrollToNextSection(e) {
    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

    //1st photo goin down
    if ( scrollPosition > 0 && currentSection === 0 ){
        $('body').stop().animate({scrollTop: windowHeight}, 700, 'linear', scrollEnded);

        if ( scrollPosition === windowHeight ){
            currentSection = 1;
        }

    }
    else if( scrollPosition < windowHeight  && currentSection === 1  ){

        $('body').stop().animate({scrollTop:(0)}, 700, 'linear', scrollEnded);

        if ( scrollPosition === 0 ){
            currentSection = 0;
        }

    }
    else if( scrollPosition > windowHeight  && currentSection === 1 ){

        $('body').stop().animate({scrollTop:(windowHeight*2)}, 700, 'linear', scrollEnded);

        if ( scrollPosition === (windowHeight*2) ){
            currentSection = 2;
        }

    }
    else if( scrollPosition < windowHeight*2 && currentSection === 2){
        $('body').stop().animate({scrollTop:(windowHeight)}, 700, 'linear', scrollEnded);

        if ( scrollPosition === windowHeight ){
            currentSection = 1;
        }
 }


}
});
```

```css
html,body{
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

img{
display: block;
height:100%; 
width:100%;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
}

#section1,#section2,#section3{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
vertical-align: top;
}
#section1{
background-color: grey;
}
#section2{
background-color: green;
}
#section3{
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='section1'></div>

<div id='section2'></div>

<div id='section3'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!, I think I would never get to this by my own.
Do you have any ideas how to solve my 2nd problem/question ?
Have a great day Tiago,.

Comment: @playinThrouLife Tricky question indeed. You'll learn how the computer reads code with time. Good luck.

Comment: @playinThrouLife I didn't noticed your second question until now tbh, but you can probably get an answer [in this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445590/jquery-animate-stop-scrolling-when-user-scrolls-manually). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I really got stuck with this one