# AngularJS / JQuery: scroll from current location to element

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-animate, scrollto

This is my current directive, which I found as the second answer to the following question - [ScrollTo function in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284005/scrollto-function-in-angularjs):

```
.directive('scrollToItem', function($timeout) {                                                      
    return {                                                                                 
        restrict: 'A',                                                                       
        scope: {                                                                             
            scrollTo: "@"                                                                    
        },                                                                                   
        link: function(scope, $elm,attr) {                                                   

            $elm.on('click', function() {                                                    
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(scope.scrollTo).offset().top }, "slow");
            });                                                                              
        }                                                                                    
    }})
```

The code above can be used like so:

```
<a id="top-scroll" name="top"></a>
<div class="back-to-top" scroll-to-item scroll-to="#top-scroll">
```

The issue is that this causes the page to quickly scroll all the way up and then animate from the top. Is there a recommended way for me to scroll from the current location to the desired position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to change

```
$elm.on('click', function() {                                                    
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(scope.scrollTo).offset().top }, "slow");
            });
```

to

```
$elm.on('click', function(e) {                                                    
    e.preventDefault();
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(scope.scrollTo).offset().top }, "slow");
});
```

which I found here: [jQuery flicker when using animate-scrollTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614446/jquery-flicker-when-using-animate-scrollto)

I'll wait and see if there is a better solution. If not, I'll just mark this one as the correct solution.